# matching triangle to div element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a triangle before a div in navigationTable using css, but I cant correctly match it with a div element.

[Here's code](https://jsfiddle.net/ddb06135/#&togetherjs=HcLVpeS9H5)

```
tmp tmp tmp
```

How solve this problem?

edit:
second problem: how to make edges of triangle smooth?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code, not a link to it. SO has a syntax highlighting feature that works pretty well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Absolute` positioned element will be relative to the next parent element with `relative` (or `absolute`) positioning.

```
.elem{
    color: dodgerblue;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position:relative; //YOU NEED THIS LINE
}

.elem:hover:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    top:0; //YOU NEED THIS LINE
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid; 
    border-width: 10px 15px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent red transparent transparent;
    left: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent; 
}
```

So what did you need. You need(ed) .elem to be relative, so that .elem:before could be positioned relative to that. You've also "forgot" to set `top` property (to 0).

Comment: YAAAS! THX BRO! it works! Also, maybe you know how to make edges of triangle smooth?

Comment: that is a not practice as you did there you know. Asking a question, me giving you an answer for what you've wanted, you marking my answer as correct one, and then removing it as a correct one, because you had additional question.... just saying.... what do you mean by "how to make edges of triangle smooth?" what you did to make a triangle. you can play with border width, and positioning of .elem:hover:before for better results.

Comment: tl;dr play with border width, and positioning of .elem:hover:before for better results. you are manipulating DOM element, so edges (smoothness) depends on that parameters